# Localization in Portable Libraries

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, localization, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

I am trying to use PL in my projects and now I stuck with localization. I moved with my Resources and LocalizedStrings to PL project. My LocalizedStrings look like this:

```
namespace Activity.Localization
{
  public class LocalizedStrings : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public LocalizedStrings()
    {
    }

    private static Resources.AppResources localizedResources = new Resources.AppResources();

    public Resources.AppResources LocalizedResources { get { return localizedResources; } }

    public void ResetResources()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("LocalizedResources");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

and resources are in Resources folder (it's auto-generated from Windows phone project).

Now in my View I have this for button (Windows Phone project, MainPage.xaml):

```
<controls:MenuButton x:Name="btnStartGame" 
                             Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.btnStartGame, Source={StaticResource localization:LocalizedStrings}}" 
                             Tap="btnStartGame_Click"
                             Height="80" Width="400" 
                             FontSize="30" Margin="12"/>
```

It compiles and build but when app start I get exception:

```
Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key localization:LocalizedStrings
```

So I think I must do some changes to get localization to portable libraries but which one? How can I change that to have it working? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your StaticResource in the App.xaml:

http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/localizing-a-windows-phone-app-step-by-step

Comment: Thanks, I totally forget on this.